# Nested loops extremely slow for coordinates generating

Tags: python, performance, loops, math, nested-loops

I am trying to build a script to produce the following coordinates result:

```
x, y:  0 0
x, y:  0 5
x, y:  0 10
=====
x, y:  5 0
x, y:  5 5
x, y:  5 10
=====
x, y:  10 0
x, y:  10 5
x, y:  10 10
=====
x, y:  0 1
x, y:  0 6
x, y:  0 11
=====
x, y:  5 1
x, y:  5 6
x, y:  5 11
=====
x, y:  10 1
x, y:  10 6
x, y:  10 11
=====
x, y:  0 2
x, y:  0 7
x, y:  0 12
=====
x, y:  5 2
x, y:  5 7
x, y:  5 12
=====
x, y:  10 2
x, y:  10 7
x, y:  10 12
=====
x, y:  0 3
x, y:  0 8
x, y:  0 13
=====
x, y:  5 3
x, y:  5 8
x, y:  5 13
=====
x, y:  10 3
x, y:  10 8
x, y:  10 13
=====
x, y:  0 4
x, y:  0 9
x, y:  0 14
=====
x, y:  5 4
x, y:  5 9
x, y:  5 14
=====
x, y:  10 4
x, y:  10 9
x, y:  10 14
=====
x, y:  1 0
x, y:  1 5
x, y:  1 10
=====
x, y:  6 0
x, y:  6 5
x, y:  6 10
=====
x, y:  11 0
x, y:  11 5
x, y:  11 10
=====
x, y:  1 1
x, y:  1 6
x, y:  1 11
=====
x, y:  6 1
x, y:  6 6
x, y:  6 11
=====
x, y:  11 1
x, y:  11 6
x, y:  11 11
=====
x, y:  1 2
x, y:  1 7
x, y:  1 12
=====
x, y:  6 2
x, y:  6 7
x, y:  6 12
=====
x, y:  11 2
x, y:  11 7
x, y:  11 12
=====
x, y:  1 3
x, y:  1 8
x, y:  1 13
=====
x, y:  6 3
x, y:  6 8
x, y:  6 13
=====
x, y:  11 3
x, y:  11 8
x, y:  11 13
=====
x, y:  1 4
x, y:  1 9
x, y:  1 14
=====
x, y:  6 4
x, y:  6 9
x, y:  6 14
=====
x, y:  11 4
x, y:  11 9
x, y:  11 14
=====
x, y:  2 0
x, y:  2 5
x, y:  2 10
=====
x, y:  7 0
x, y:  7 5
x, y:  7 10
=====
x, y:  12 0
x, y:  12 5
x, y:  12 10
=====
x, y:  2 1
x, y:  2 6
x, y:  2 11
=====
x, y:  7 1
x, y:  7 6
x, y:  7 11
=====
x, y:  12 1
x, y:  12 6
x, y:  12 11
=====
x, y:  2 2
x, y:  2 7
x, y:  2 12
=====
x, y:  7 2
x, y:  7 7
x, y:  7 12
=====
x, y:  12 2
x, y:  12 7
x, y:  12 12
=====
x, y:  2 3
x, y:  2 8
x, y:  2 13
=====
x, y:  7 3
x, y:  7 8
x, y:  7 13
=====
x, y:  12 3
x, y:  12 8
x, y:  12 13
=====
x, y:  2 4
x, y:  2 9
x, y:  2 14
=====
x, y:  7 4
x, y:  7 9
x, y:  7 14
=====
x, y:  12 4
x, y:  12 9
x, y:  12 14
=====
x, y:  3 0
x, y:  3 5
x, y:  3 10
=====
x, y:  8 0
x, y:  8 5
x, y:  8 10
=====
x, y:  13 0
x, y:  13 5
x, y:  13 10
=====
x, y:  3 1
x, y:  3 6
x, y:  3 11
=====
x, y:  8 1
x, y:  8 6
x, y:  8 11
=====
x, y:  13 1
x, y:  13 6
x, y:  13 11
=====
x, y:  3 2
x, y:  3 7
x, y:  3 12
=====
x, y:  8 2
x, y:  8 7
x, y:  8 12
=====
x, y:  13 2
x, y:  13 7
x, y:  13 12
=====
x, y:  3 3
x, y:  3 8
x, y:  3 13
=====
x, y:  8 3
x, y:  8 8
x, y:  8 13
=====
x, y:  13 3
x, y:  13 8
x, y:  13 13
=====
x, y:  3 4
x, y:  3 9
x, y:  3 14
=====
x, y:  8 4
x, y:  8 9
x, y:  8 14
=====
x, y:  13 4
x, y:  13 9
x, y:  13 14
=====
x, y:  4 0
x, y:  4 5
x, y:  4 10
=====
x, y:  9 0
x, y:  9 5
x, y:  9 10
=====
x, y:  14 0
x, y:  14 5
x, y:  14 10
=====
x, y:  4 1
x, y:  4 6
x, y:  4 11
=====
x, y:  9 1
x, y:  9 6
x, y:  9 11
=====
x, y:  14 1
x, y:  14 6
x, y:  14 11
=====
x, y:  4 2
x, y:  4 7
x, y:  4 12
=====
x, y:  9 2
x, y:  9 7
x, y:  9 12
=====
x, y:  14 2
x, y:  14 7
x, y:  14 12
=====
x, y:  4 3
x, y:  4 8
x, y:  4 13
=====
x, y:  9 3
x, y:  9 8
x, y:  9 13
=====
x, y:  14 3
x, y:  14 8
x, y:  14 13
=====
x, y:  4 4
x, y:  4 9
x, y:  4 14
=====
x, y:  9 4
x, y:  9 9
x, y:  9 14
=====
x, y:  14 4
x, y:  14 9
x, y:  14 14
=====
```

Creating Nested loops seemed to be the cleanest approach:

```
el_x = 5
el_y = 5

h4d_x = 15
h4d_y = 15

for i in range(el_x):
    for j in range(el_y):
        for x in range(0, h4d_x, el_x):
            for y in range(0, h4d_y, el_y):
                print('x, y: ', x+i, y+j)
            print('=====')
```

The piece of code does ok with the current variables, but I would like to use it for way larger numbers, for example:

```
# el_x = 100
# el_y = 100

# h4d_x = 7900
# h4d_y = 5300
```

Is there a way to minimise the use of loops in this case?

**Edit**:

I’m only printing the data in this example because I wanted to check the values. I’m generating these values (x, y) as image pixels coordinates, that i need to use in that specific order.

Comment: Your code takes nearly all the time to print data (inherently slow), and to format strings. You are trying to write a code printing at least `100*100*7900*5300*12/1024**3 = 4679 GiB` of data! This does not make any sense. Why on earth would you do that? Btw, loops are the least of your problems.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do? For coordinate mesh generation, you can use numpy's [`meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) and related.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I’m only printing the data in this example because I wanted to check the values. I’m generating these values (x, y) as image pixels coordinates, that i need to use in that specific order

Comment: Ok. The default implementation of Python is an interpreter: CPython. It is very slow for loops and in fact it is not design for intensive computations but just use as a glue language, for scripting.or prototyping. Because of this, the main way to get efficient code is to call C code from CPython. This is called vectorization. The thing is that to vectorize a code, a complete code of the loop is required. It is not possible to decouple the iteration of the loop from its content with this method.

Comment: If you want loops like this to be fast independently of the content, then you need to use another language (a native *compiled* one like C/C++). Using tools like Cython or Numba is possible but they are not as flexible (and Numba is not for general purpose code). Like PierreD said, this is an XY problem and so you need to reconsider what you want as long as you need to use CPython (not directly designed for you need). Regarding the size of your problem, I highly recommend you to use a compiled language (unless waiting for a long time is fine).